# Snakemake help function

Tags: snakemake

What's a good way to add a help function to my Snakemake pipeline to describe config parameter usage? I'm seeing [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/344604/) for printing rule docstrings, but I'm not sure if/how that can be used for config values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with vanilla Snakemake.

However, this is possible with snakeparse: https://github.com/nh13/snakeparse. Unfortunately, the project has not been updated since April 2018 (as of August 18th, 2021).

Answer (score 0):

If coming from a `configfile: "config.yaml"`, the `config` object will be a dictionary which one could iterate through. A basic example would be simply listing the keys:

**Snakefile**

```python
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule help:
  run:
    print("Configuration keys:")
    for k in config.keys():
      print(k)
```

On the more sophisticated end, I would consider creating [a JSON schema for validating the parameters](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#validation) and then write a function to print the JSON schema file in a pretty way, since that validation file should contain all the pertinent information about the parameters.